# Error while launching CF Template for CloudHSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudhsm

```html
{
    "Resources": {
        "Cluster": {
            "Type" : "AWS::CloudHSM::Cluster",
            "Properties":{
            "VpcId": "vpc-50ae0636",
            "SubnetMapping": {
                "us-west-1b": "subnet-49a1bc00",
                "us-west-1c": "subnet-6f950334",
                "us-west-1a": "subnet-fd54af9b"
            },
            "SecurityGroup": "sg-6cb2c216",
            "HsmType": "hsm1.medium",
            "Certificates": {},
            "State": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "Hsms": [],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to launch a cluster in CloudHSM using CF Template. I am facing this issue. 
"Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::HSM::Cluster]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWS::CloudHSM::Cluster` is not a valid resource type.  Unfortunately, Cloudformation does not support all services or may have an incomplete set of supported resources.

Here is a list of valid services and resource types currently supported by CloudFormation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html

The Cloudformation team is pushing out support for new resources very frequently.  You can monitor this page to see when they push out support for new features:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html

Answer (score 1):

As of now, CloudHSM cant be done via CF. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudhsmv2.html#CloudHSMV2.Client.create_cluster.

Can be done via custom resource, that's done by using Lambda. Or CLI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudhsmv2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

CloudHSM is currently not supported by CloudFormation.
You can find a list of supported services and ressource types [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html).